# Are there any statistics about most common account thefts?

Tags: account-security

I am trying to evaluate how safe personal accounts are (including my own).
Are there any statistics on the top security flaws which cause accounts to be compromised/stolen?
Like: 25% of cases is common password, 13% of cases is malware accessing passwords in browsers, 10% is password interception on an unsecure channel etc.

I know what I have to do in order to make an account fully secure (end-to-end cryptography using a physical key for both authentication and data), but there is a balance between risk and cost of counter-measures (especially considering the low number of online services offering end-to-end encryption).

Comment: You're missing the top item: phishing, where users simply give the account info over or running malware. Do you mean technical flaws?

Comment: You're also missing the top technical root cause: password database dumps. You do you mean *user-enabled* technical vulnerabilities leading to account compromise?

Comment: And, over what time period? The situation changes pretty rapidly.

Comment: I'm not sure about e2e encryption for account and data, but 2FA is the number one measure you can take, and it is free.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to check lists of top vulnerabilities or top leaks causes and extract what you consider relevant to your context.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. 1 - I'm not really vulnerable to phishing, so it's reassuring to know it's the top item. 2 - any way for the user to avoid password database dumps? 3 - OK for 2FA, but I'm also using "app-specific passwords" from Google for devices that don't handle OAuth, and I'm trying to assess the security it provides.